# Ant to replace file text that does not starts with 

Tags: regex, file-io, ant, regex-negation

I want to make an ant target that can replace the content of a file (or more) that does not starts with a defined pattern. Is there a solution for this using ant and replaceregexp ? Or an alternative to this?
Example:

- I have file boo.txt that has the text:
  "this is boo".
- Also I have the file foo.txt that has the text:
  "just foo".

I want to change the text for the foo.txt to:
"this just foo"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a case of cooking up a suitable regular expression with captures.

This one appears to work for the example you give.

```
<property name="prefix" value="this " />
<replaceregexp flags="s" match="^(${prefix})?(.*)" replace="${prefix}\2">
    <fileset dir="files" />
</replaceregexp>
```

- The files are specified using a fileset - here all files in the `files` directory.
- The prefix we want to optionally add is `this`, which is stored in a property, as we need to mention it in two places.
- The `flags="s"` setting ensures that we treat the file as a single string for match purposes (rather than matching each line).
- The regular expression looks for the prefix string in the file, and stores it in capture `\1` - which is discarded.
- The rest of the string is in capture `\2`.
- Replace with the prefix string, followed by capture `\2`.

You might think of it as always adding the prefix, but *after taking the prefix away if it's already there*...except that the [`replaceregexp`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task will *not* write the file unless if differs from the existing.

Comment: Wow, very elegant solution, thanks! I found something similar using look around and look ahead but this is simpler!

Comment: Do you have an ideea how to escape regex special chars inside the prefix property value?

Answer (score 0):

this is just a partial answer.. I'm not sure if its correct but at least maybe can give you some direction

for this you need ant-contrib

```
    <property name="folder.name" value="some-folder-name" />
    <property name="text.substitution" value="this " />

    <target name="main">
       <foreach target="target2" param="file_path"> 
          <path> 
             <fileset dir="${folder.name}" casesensitive="no" /> 
          </path> 
       </foreach>
    </target>

<target name="target2">
    <loadfile property="message" srcFile="${file_path}"/>
        <!-- f message doesnt have text.substitution at the begging -->
        <!-- not sure if this is correct regex -->
        <propertyregex property="myprop" input="${message}" 
                      regexp="([^b]+)" select="\0" casesensitive="false" /> 
    <if>
        <equals arg1="${myprop}" arg2="{text.substitution}" />      
    <then>
        <concat destfile="foo.txt" append="true">${text.substitution} </concat>  
    </then>
    </if>
</target>
```